# Add UIView in Main View As UItabBarController in swift

Tags: swift

I am adding Tabbarcontroller in Main View, but i didn't set its background colour...
 I have already try `tabBar.barTintColor` but it's not working..

So i am trying to Add View as TabbarController (Which work  like UITabbar) but i am not succeeded on it...
 Can any one please help me out.
Here is the code

```
var tabBar = UITabBarController()

    var frameOfView : CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    tabBar.view.frame = CGRectMake(frameOfView.origin.x, frameOfView.size.height, frameOfView.size.width, frameOfView.size.height-100)

    var viewTabBar = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(frameOfView.origin.x, 430, frameOfView.size.width, 100))
    var BtnHomeTab = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30))
    var imageHomeTab = UIImage(named: "home_selected.png")
    viewTabBar.addSubview(BtnHomeTab)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have to hide UITabbarcontroller ..:)

and then Add this code to Your appDelegate.

```
 //MARK: CREATE BOTTOMBAR BUTTON
func craeteBottonBarButton()
{
    var viewBottom : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,window!.frame.size.height - 50.0,window!.frame.size.width,60.0))
    viewBottom.tag = TagWindow.Tag_Bottom.rawValue
    window!.addSubview(viewBottom)
    window!.bringSubviewToFront(viewBottom)
    viewBottom.backgroundColor = GlobalConstants.GlobalConstants.ButtonConstant.BUTTONBACKGROUNDCOLOR
    viewBottom.tag = TagWindow.Tag_Bottom.rawValue

    var x : CGFloat = 0.0
    for  var i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++
    {
       var btn = createTabBarButton(viewBottom,
            framebtn: CGRectMake(x,0, 65.0, 50.0),
            tag: (i + 1),
            imgName: arrayImage.objectAtIndex(i) as NSString , btnName: arrayLblName.objectAtIndex(i) as NSString) as UIButton
        viewBottom.addSubview(btn)
        x += 64.5
    }
}
```

Give all navigation controller to the button

```
func createTabBar() -> UITabBarController
{
    var storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    tabBar.delegate = self
    var tabBarFont = UITabBar()

    let HomeTab = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeVC") as HomeVC
    let navigation_home = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeTab)
    navigation_home.navigationBarHidden = true

    let SearchTab = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SearchVC") as SearchVC
    let navigation_search = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SearchTab)
    navigation_search.navigationBarHidden = true

    let SettingTab = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SettingVC") as SettingVC
    let navigation_Setting = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SettingTab)
    navigation_Setting.navigationBarHidden = true

    let MySeatTab = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MySeatVC") as MySeatVC
    let navigation_MySeat = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MySeatTab)
    navigation_MySeat.navigationBarHidden = true
```